# Wired memory increase in nodejs iterations on mac os x

Tags: node.js, macos, memory, memory-leaks

When trying to do a loop with unknown number of iterations I noticed that the wired memory on my mac just kept on increasing. I have following code

```
var Iteration = function () {
    this.counter = 0;
};
Iteration.prototype.go = function () {

    global.gc();
    var util = require('util');

    console.log('%s, %s', ++this.counter, util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));

    var self = this;

    var largeArray = new Array(1e4);
    var l = largeArray.length;

    for(var i = 0; i<l; i++) {

        largeArray[i] = new Array(l);

        for(var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            largeArray[i][j] = j+0.1;
        }
    }

    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        self.go();
        t = null;
    }, 10);

};

var iteration = new Iteration();
iteration.go();
```

When I run it  with --expose-gc flag on mac with 0.10.33 node, the rss and heap footprint are stabilised. However, my system monitor shows persistent increase in wired memory until my mac crashes (10.9.5). Currently I do not have other system to test it on so I was wondering if anyone else has seen this kind of behaviour or can explain why this is happening.

I have tested the same code on ubuntu on virtual box and it seems there is no problem with increased wired memory. So this issue can be either mac related or related to the nodejs build for mac.